# Using 3d transformation matrices

Tags: java, 3d, matrix

In an AI class we have a robot that has an arm with 7 joints.  Each joint can rotate a different direction.  I need to know where the very end is going to be.  I've been trying to do 3d matrix multiplication and it works for one joint but once I add in another it doesn't line up with a model I made using the Java3D api.  This is how I'm trying to calculate the position of the second joint.

```
double[][] b = {{0, 0, 0, 1}};

// Joint 1
b = HercMatrix.MatMul(b, HercMatrix.getTranslation(0, 0, -110));
b = HercMatrix.MatMul(b, HercMatrix.getRotation(0, arm.getJointAngle(0), 0));

// Joint 2
b = HercMatrix.MatMul(b, HercMatrix.getTranslation(0, 0, -250));
b = HercMatrix.MatMul(b, HercMatrix.getRotation(arm.getJointAngle(1), 0, 0));

System.out.println("Matrix: " + b[0][0] + ", " + b[0][1] + ", " + b[0][2]);
```

I imagine it's they way I go about applying the multiplications.  I know for a fact it's not my matmul or matrice generation code, I've tested all that individually.

the second translation I have needs to be on the relative x-axis of the first joint's angle.  But I have no idea if this is how I do it...

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer exactly without seeing the structure of your affine transformation matrices, and the definitions of the angle variables. The normal definition of the [translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)#Matrix_representation) assumes the position vector is multiplied from the left, for example, which seems to be opposite to your use. Check also that b[0][3]==1 at the end.

You code seems to be equivalent to the following pseudocode:

```
b = origin.translate(Joint1).rotate(Joint1).translate(Joint2).rotate(Joint2);
```

This is not equivalent to

```
b = origin.translate(Joint2).rotate(Joint2).translate(Joint1).rotate(Joint1);
```

so check which order of transformations you require.

Comment: This actually was the problem.  Thank you for your advice!